# show that $\mathscr X_B$ is lower semicontinuous if and only if B is open

Tags: real-analysis

I have a doubt concerning the following problem:

"Given $B \subseteq \mathbb R$, let $\mathscr X_B: \mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R $ be the characteristic function of $B$ defined as $\mathscr X_B(x)=1$, if $x \in B$ and $\mathscr X_B(x)=0$ if $x \notin B$. Show that $\mathscr X_B$ is lower semicontinuous if and only if $B$ is open".

Well, $\mathscr X_B(x)$ lower semicontinuous at a point $x_b \in \mathbb R$ $\Rightarrow \forall \varepsilon > 0, \exists \delta >0$ such that $x \in \mathbb R, |x-x_b|< \delta \rightarrow \mathscr X_B (x) > \mathscr X_B(x_b) - \varepsilon$

$x_b \in B$ $\Rightarrow$ $\mathscr X_B(x_b) = 1$

Now, supose $x \in B$. Then, $\mathscr X_B(x) = 1$ and $1=1- \varepsilon$, by the definition of semicontinuity, which is an absurd.

Comment: By the definition of lower semicontinuous function you provided us with, I read $1>1-\epsilon$, which is true for all $\epsilon>0$.

Comment: Sorry. $x \notin B \Rightarrow \mathscr X_B(x)=0$" and $0> 1- \varepsilon$

Comment: $0>1-\epsilon$ iff  $\epsilon>1$, but in your statement there is $\forall \epsilon >0 ...$